# MVC 6 - Razor Views in Class Library tag "Model" with a does not exist error

Tags: visual-studio, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

Visual Studio (2015) is underlining all my references to "Model" in the Class Library Razor views and giving this error message:

`The name "Model" does not exist in the current context`

I have seen a lot of questions asking this sort of thing in an earlier version of ASP.Net and MVC but not much for this version.

Since these Razor views are setup as an embedded resource they are compiling fine and running fine. They just give me errors in the editor.

In the project.json file I have a reference to Razor Tools that I thought should fix this:

```
"dependencies": {
   "ApolloWeb.Common": "1.0.0-*",
   "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "5.2.3",
   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures": "1.0.1",
   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
       "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
       "type": "build"
   },
   "Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded": "1.0.0",
   "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1-preview1-24530-04"
},     
"tools": {
   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
},
 "frameworks": {
   "net46": {}
},
 "buildOptions": {
   "embed": [ "_Views/**" ],
   "preserveCompilationContext": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered what my issue was.

I copied all the packages that the MVC template pulled into the Main MVC project and started removing them until I reached the one that reproduced the issue.

I was missing a dependency on this package:

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
```